# Edit data in an ArcGIS Service via rest and json with jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, openlayers-3, arcgis

i'm trying to change information from a feature from an arcgis service via rest and json. I have made a function that will be called but the result is giving me no idea what to do.

I'm using openlayers3 as well and i know it has the function *feature.setProperties* but i`m not sure how to actually put that towards a service. i have checked this example to understand it:
http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-esri-edit.html?q=arcgis
but sadly i do not, because i can't create the payload variable.

But if there is a way to do it with openlayers3 i`m even happier.

The code i use is:

```
export function changeFeature(feature) {
var str = {};
str = feature.getProperties();

for (var s in str) {
    if (typeof str[s] === 'object') {

    } else {
        str[s] = document.getElementById(''+s + '1').value;
        feature[s] = document.getElementById(''+s + '1').value;
    }
};

console.log(str);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://192.168.216.56:6080/arcgis/rest/services/test/MyMapService/FeatureServer/0/applyEdits",
    data: str,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    processData: true,
    success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
        alert("success..." + data);
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
});
```

}

And the console will give me this:

```
Object { geometry: Object, 
         objectid: "56400", 
         relcp86d_: "0", 
         relcp86d_i: "564", 
         symbol: "4", 
         polygonid: "0", 
         scale: "1", 
         angle: "0", 
         omschrijvi: "Rosmolen" }
```

which looks okay but then it throws me this error:

```
TypeError: event is undefined[Meer info]
```

Answer (score 1):

here is an Esri documentation to use Applyedit: http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/apis/rest/fsedits.html

so to update a feature, you have to send a json with two objects :

- one is the geometry, which contains the X,Y coordinates of the feature
- the other is the attributes, with the OBJECTID key-value pair, and other attributes pair to update.